# magento 2 data migration tool ignore table by mask

Tags: magento2, data-migration

I'm creating map.xml file to ignore some tables in DB. And I have a lot of tables with prefix 'old'. Can I create one rule for all this tables and don't create one by one? Something like

```
<ignore>
    <document>old*</document>
</ignore>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

today I found a solution. It's works for me.

```
<ignore>
    <document>old_*</document>
</ignore>
```

In my DB I have a lot of tables like "old_widget_instance_page_layout" and I don't want to use them in migration.